# Biblatex's citesetup and citetext

Tags: biblatex, formatting, citing

I am using biblatex to make the citation numbers bold by redefining `\citesetup` to include a `\bfseries`:

```
\renewcommand*{\citesetup}{%
\bfseries
\biburlsetup
\frenchspacing}
```

This makes the reference `\cite{key}` appear as

> **[1]**

as desired. The problem is that sometimes I want to use `\textcite` to also include the author's name, but still with a bold citation number, i.e., the command `\textcite{key}` should produce

> author's name **[1]**

With my redefined `\citesetup` this is not achieved since it makes the author's name as well as the citation number bold, i.e.,

> **author's name [1]**

Does anybody know of a good way to achieve the desired effect with a partial bold reference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a solution that redefines the `textcite` bibmacro (as found in the `numeric` citestyle), defines a new `\mkbibboldbrackets` command and applies it to various citation commands (replacing `\mkbibbrackets`). Note that this way pre- and postnotes still will be typeset in bold.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\makeatletter

\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\cbx@tempa
     \ifnameundef{labelname}
       {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
       {\printnames{labelname}}%
%     \addspace\bibopenbracket}% DELETED
     \addspace\begingroup\bfseries\bibopenbracket}% ADDED
  \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{cite}%
  \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
%  \gdef\cbx@tempa{\bibclosebracket\multicitedelim}}% DELETED
  \gdef\cbx@tempa{\textbf{\bibclosebracket}\multicitedelim}}% ADDED

\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}
  {\let\cbx@tempa=\empty
   \undef\cbx@lasthash}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{textcite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}%
%   \bibclosebracket}% DELETED
   \bibclosebracket\endgroup}% ADDED

\newrobustcmd{\mkbibboldbrackets}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@blxinit
  \blx@setsfcodes
  \bfseries\bibopenbracket#1\bibclosebracket
  \endgroup}

\makeatother

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibboldbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibboldbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\smartcite}[\iffootnote\mkbibboldbrackets\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cites}[\mkbibboldbrackets]{\cite}{\multicitedelim}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\parencites}[\mkbibboldbrackets]{\parencite}{\multicitedelim}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\smartcites}[\iffootnote\mkbibboldbrackets\mkbibfootnote]{\smartcite}{\multicitedelim}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text about \textcite{companion} and \textcite[see][99]{knuth:ct:a}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative that typesets only the label (and not the surrounding brackets) in bold is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \textbf{% ADDED
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield{prefixnumber}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}%
    \ifbool{bbx:subentry}
      {\printfield{entrysetcount}}
%      {}}}% DELETED
      {}}}}% ADDED

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text about \textcite{companion} and \textcite[see][99]{knuth:ct:a}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Robert Please also upvote my answer -- this has to be done separately from accepting it.

Comment: Sorry for my late response, lockstep. It has been upvoted now.